# Do I need to ground this switch?

Tags: electrical

I am trying to replace a standard one pole switch with a dimmer.  When I took off the switch the grounding screw was not attached to anything and I can not see a grounding wire in the box.  The house was completely renovated by a developer in 2012 and my impression is that new electrical installations should have grounding (although I realize there may be additional rules around GFCI, etc). My questions are:
 1) what should I do about grounding?
 2) should this switch have had grounding?

Attaching images of the switch, box and circuit breaker.  Not the box has additional wires because there is another switch box behind it for the room on the other side of the wall

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 5):

### You have a ground already.  It's called "conduit".

The locknut at the top of the box and the presence of the red and yellow wires with no black wire are dead giveaways that this installation uses *metallic conduit*, which is an able ground conductor all by its lonesome.

Normally, with a metal box, you'd simply make sure the switch yoke seats against the mounting ears on the box, grounding it as per 404.9(B)(1).  However, since some dimwit painted the mounting ears on the switch, you'll need to install a grounding jumper from the ground screw on the switch to a ground screw on the back of the box.

> **(B) Grounding.** Snap switches, including dimmer and similar control switches, shall be connected to an equipment
>   grounding conductor and shall provide a means to connect
>   metal faceplates to the equipment grounding conductor,
>   whether or not a metal faceplate is installed. Snap switches
>   shall be considered to be part of an effective ground-fault
>   current path if either of the following conditions is met:
>
> (1) The switch is mounted with metal screws to a metal
>   box or metal cover that is connected to an equipment
>   grounding conductor or to a nonmetallic box with integral means for connecting to an equipment grounding
>   conductor.
>
> 2) An equipment grounding conductor or equipment
>   bonding jumper is connected to an equipment grounding termination of the snap switch.

Comment: It looks as though the drywall may keep the switch from making contact with the mud ring. If that is the case you will need a jumper wire from the ground terminal on the switch to the junction box.

Comment: @ArchonOSX -- it's nothing a deeper mud ring couldn't fix, or adjusting the ears on the switch so that they fit within the drywall

Comment: The mud ring is painted, and that is likely to act as an electrical insulator. The threaded screws will make good electrical contact with the threaded holes in the mud ring, and will be in contact with the metal on the switch. But that's a loose connection. I would just screw a ground wire to the box and to the switch.

Comment: Thanks @ThreePhaseEel   Very clear - appreciate the help.

Comment: True you could snap the ears off the switch so will make solid contact with the mud ring. The receptacle may set back a little in the wall then. Replacing the mud ring though would involve removing, patching, and re-painting the drywall. 

Answer (score 2):

That installation looks like EMT conduit and metal boxes. In that system, the conduit is the ground, and that entire metal box is grounded.

Here is where interpret code conservatively.  If the switch's drywall ears rested firmly on the bare-metal box, and the screws were torqued down tight, I call that "good to go".  You don't have that here.  You notice the switch's drywall ears rest on the drywall, and that leaves a significant gap (1/4") between the switch ears and the metal box.  Nothing bridges that gap but screws, and I say screws are not enough.

That metal box looks to be a spacious 4x4 metal box, with a 1-gang (2x4) "mud ring" on the front, which narrows it somewhat and makes it fit well to drywall. In the back of the 4x4 metal box, there are several holes.  One of them is tapped with 10-32 threads.  That is designed for a ground screw, and you can attach a ground pigtail from that to the switch.

They sell special green screws for 99 cents a bag, and sell screws with pigtails preattached for $3 or so.  Bare wire of the same size as the conductors will suffice.  (12AWG if the breaker is 20A, 14AWG if the breaker is 15A).